# How do I display both header and source file in Borland Builder XE?

Tags: c++builder, usability, c++builder-xe

Does someone know how to display both the header and source file at once in the builder XE?

I know I can toggle between them, but I'd rather have a tab for each file.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, the IDE should not be displaying the files side by side at the same time.  Related files (such as .cpp, .h, and .dfm for a given Unit) are displayed as a group, where there is only 1 tab up top for the group, and separate tabs down below for the individual files of the group.

[image: Code Editor]

If you are able to display the individual files side by side with their own top-level tabs, then the files are likely not being grouped together correctly, such as if the file names do not match each other, or the header file guard in the .h file is named incorrectly.

Comment: @confusedandtired me neither, I've always rightclick -> swap header/source

Comment: You can also use CTRL-F6 to toggle between the source and header files.

Answer (score 5):

Further to the answer posted by Remy Lebeau, the "magic" form for the header file guard is `<filename>H`. For example, the source file pair Foo.cpp/Foo.h requires that the define be `FooH` in Foo.h.

For new forms, RAD Studio will take care of this naming for you, but for non-visual file units, you may need to make these changes manually. You may even need to edit the .cbprof file to add the `<DependentOn>Foo.h</DependentOn>` to the `<CppCompile Include="Foo.cpp">` tag.

Comment: explaining this a bit more: the IDE will automatically create a `<DependentOn>` entry if you add a `.cpp` file to the project, and there is a corresponding `.h` file with that format `<filename>H` in the include guard.  Otherwise you have to do it manually.  The "bloc" of files as shown in Remy's screenshot consists of a `.cpp` file and everything that it is `DependentOn`.

Comment: "<filename>H" --------- That fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to View->New Edit Window

Comment: No, not quite. 

I somehow managed to open both .cpp and .h file but I don't know how I did it, I just noticed it now